# How can I set up a FAQ page in a booklet?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, text

I want to set up a simple FAQ page at the end of a booklet I'm working on.

The format will be:

Q. The text of the question.

A. The text of the answer.

I want the text to be left-aligned, but to the right of the Q and the A, not under them. There will be multiple questions and answers per page, but I'm not worried about line breaks as I can organise the questions and answers so that they don't run over a page end.

Any ideas? I need this for an end-of-year project I'm working on.

Comment: Will the texts be longer than a line, and if so, should the text start at the very left (under the A) or a little indented (so that the A would still fit there)?

Comment: The questions can be one or two lines, but the answers can be several lines long. The questions and answers must be indented to the right of the Q and the A, not under them.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}    %% just for demo

\newlist{question}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[question,1]{
  label= \textbf{Q.},
  leftmargin=*,
}
\newlist{answer}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[answer,1]{
  label= \textbf{A.},
  leftmargin=*,
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{question}
    \item \lipsum*[1]
  \end{question}
  \begin{answer}
    \item \lipsum*[1]
  \end{answer}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjusting other parameters like `topsep`, `itemsep` etc is home work for the weekend `:-)` (hint: consult `enumitem` manual)

Answer (score 3):

Other simple way:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{octavo}
\usepackage[paperwidth=108mm, paperheight=120mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\parskip1em
\def\Q{\noindent\hangindent3em\makebox[3em][l]{‪\bfseries Q.}} 
\def\A{\noindent\hangindent3em\makebox[3em][l]{‪\bfseries A.}} 
\begin{document}

\section*{FAQ's}

\Q How can I set up a \textsc{faq} page in a booklet? 
I want to set up a simple \textsc{faq} page at the end 
of a booklet I'm working on.

\A You can use an \verb|\hanindent| plus a \verb|\makebox|, 
both of the same width. A simple macro can simplfy 
typesetting this.

\Q Can I see some example?

\A Yes, of course, see the source code of this file 
in \TeX-\LaTeX\ Stack Exchange.
\footnote{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274775/11604}}

\end{document}
```